# SQL query to replace a string and convert rest of the string to Int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query. This query is supposed to look into my accounts table with my where parameter. That will return all account codes which start with leading 3 letters "DAG". The data return is consistently in the format leading with three letters followed by a number. I then want to get the most largest number. For that I order the string by converting it to Int.

I get this below error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   Invalid column name 'AccountCodeWithoutDAG '.

Here is my SQL query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    REPLACE(AccountCode, 'DAG', '') AS AccountCodeWithoutDAG 
FROM 
    Accounts 
WHERE
    MangCode = 'ADFG'  
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(INT, AccountCodeWithoutDAG)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...

Comment: WHERE comes after FROM

Comment: sorry that was my bad copy pasting it. I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `order by` with `convert` alias

but you can try to use a subquery to get the `AccountCodeWithoutDAG` then `order by` it

```
SELECT  TOP 1 AccountCodeWithoutDAG 
FROM 
(
    SELECT REPLACE(AccountCode,'DAG','') AS AccountCodeWithoutDAG
    FROM Accounts 
    where  MangCode = 'ADFG'  
) t1
Order by  Convert(int, AccountCodeWithoutDAG )
```

Comment: I'm curious how this performs against just repeating the convert in the select and the orderby. Feels a lot cleaner to do it the other way

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, giving a calculated value an alias in the `select` does not give you the ability to use the same alias in subsequent clauses.

The way to do this nice-and-organized in sql server is `cross apply`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 AccountCodeWithoutDAG
FROM Accounts 
cross apply (select REPLACE(AccountCode,'DAG','') AS AccountCodeWithoutDAG ) as calcquery
where 
   MangCode = 'ADFG'  
   Order by Convert(int, AccountCodeWithoutDAG )
```

Comment: You gotta love the cross apply! Many awesome uses!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the AccountCodeWithoutDAG, this is an alias and cannot be used in the order
Look what I did in testing below , use your replace statement in the convert part of the order by

```
declare @AccountCode varchar(100)='DAG123456'

SELECT  top 1 REPLACE(@AccountCode,'DAG','') AS AccountCodeWithoutDAG 
   Order by Convert(int, REPLACE(@AccountCode,'DAG',''))
```

Comment: ORDER by runs after the SELECT statement hence the Alias is visible

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran Totally depends on which version of sql server he's using. What you describe is a fairly new feature